# Gravity on WebView after loadurl

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, webview, android-webview

Hi I have a WebView defined like the one above:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/home_banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

When the WebView loads the banner, it lose the gravity attribute, placing it to the left of the LinearLAyout, creating a lot of empty space to the right.

There is any way to fix this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you want? do you want the webview at the center of the layout?

Comment: +Pramod, yes, that's exactly what I want. But when I load the URL, the WebView it's not centered horizontally.

Comment: Is this your complete layout?

Comment: +Pramod, this is a part of the layout. It's not necessary show the entire layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this    

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/home_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```